# Magento 1.9.2.4 customer import error

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export

I've exported trough `Customer > Export [CSV]` all my customers from the old 1.9.2.4 Magento installation and now i'm trying to import them into the freash installation, same version of Magento but when i try to import the csv i get this error:

```
Can not find required columns: email, _website
```

When i open the csv there is actually an Email column but not a _website column.

Is there something i can do? Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow following three steps and re-import it.

1) Export customers file from newer version and compare it with older versions in any csv editor.

2) correct columns in older csv and change them as per newer csv order

3) if _website (or any other column) missing in older version add it in an appropriate position as per newer file position.

Comment: Thank you Hassan, it worked, i had to add the email column, for whatever reason it didn't export it :D